# Какую книгу по C# читать после книги Троелсена?

Tags: c#, .net, книги

Какую книгу стоит читать после книги Троелсена? Какую книгу взять следующей для чтения из данных книг:

- C# 4.0 in a Nutshell, Fourth Edition
- Рихтер
- Skeet Jon C# in Depth

Comment: C# 4.0 in a Nutshell

Comment: Книга не поможет. Нужно проект делать/доделывать. А там всплывут вопросы. Вот когда их соберется несколько - вот тогда идти в библиотеку/книжный магазин (не обязательно онлайн, можно и оффлайн). Там смотреть книги и узнавать.

Comment: Рихтер, как и Скит необходимы для шлифовки знаний, но если вы начинающий в области дотнета, то далее надо набирать практику.

Answer (score 3):

Просто читать книгу по программированию смысла нет, т.к. без набора кода информации останется не много. Я бы рекомендовал делать так:

придумать задачу, которую хотите решить (например, каталог книг для хранения у себя на ПК);

выбрать технологию (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, Silverlight), если только прочитали книгу, то лучше начать с Форм, т.к. другие технологии потребуют знаний разметки (XAML, HTML и т.п.), очень хорошего понимания ООП (WPF там на паттернах все :));

и писать код... в процессе вы наступите на кучу граблей, полезете в книги, в сеть... начнете думать над архитектурой.

А вообще если поняли ООП рекомендую почитать [**Приёмы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785496003896&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0). Читается сложно, но если поймете - посмотрите на программы по другому :).

По C# Рихтера рекомендую. (Сам начинал с Троелсена)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал Герберта Шилдта, он вообще хороший специалист, у него очень хороший справочник по языку C#.

Можете для общего развития почитать его же книжку по с++

Answer (score 0):

C# 5.0 in a Nutshell (да есть уже издание про 5.0) - хороший учебник по языку. Он есть на русском и называется "C# 5.0 Справочник Полное описание языка". Там очень подробно разобраны нюансы базовых типов, специфики работы коллекций, сериализации. Есть много полезных примеров про криптование, динамическую компиляцию, внедрение в программу на C# интерпретируемого кода на Питоне. 
Если не перечитать, то иметь на столе полезно.

По асинхронному программированию неплохая книга "Асинхронное программирование в C# 5.0" Алекс Девис. Она есть на litres.ru в электронном виде и не дорого.

По разработке бизнес-логики советую почитать "C# и CSLA .NET Framework. Разработка бизнес-объектов" Рокфорд Лотка

Comment: не стоит воскрешать старые вопросы по книгам - их все равно закроют. лучше отредактируйте ответ в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0 - допишите туда то, что считаете нужным.